# What is a Transaction Check Error ? (yum update)

Tags: fedora, centos, yum, upgrade

I tried today to replace packages from atomiccorp's repositories with newer packages from the epel/remi repositories and received `Transaction Check Error`s.

I cannot proceed with my update.

```
Install       5 Package(s)
Upgrade      23 Package(s)

Total size: 24 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.3.6-1.el5.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.2.17-1.el5.art.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz from install of php-cli-5.3.6-1.el5.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.2.17-1.el5.art.i386

Error Summary
-------------
```

What is a `Transaction Check Error` and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the error messages, it looks like your upgrade is trying to upgrade your 5.3.6 version of PHP to an older version (5.2.17), and it's running into conflicts.

Did you add an extra repo in the past?

What is the output of

```
yum list *php*
```

I'd expect that you have 2 different repos listing PHP. On that assumption, the fix would be to exclude the older version of PHP in your /etc/yum.repos.d/ dir.

Alternatively, you can exclude the specific offending packages on the command line. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-centos-linux-yum-update-exclude-packages/

Comment: thank you, i didn't know that excluding specific packages is possible. my workaround was always to use yum update --enablerepo=xxx . regards

Comment: Great link, I have used `yum --exclude=texstudio update` on Fedora 19.