# How to find out which repo lists libganglia-3.7.2 and to exclude this older version in my /etc/yum.repos.d/ dir?

Tags: centos, system-installation, repository, ganglia

I encountered a "Transaction check error" when updating the CentOS 7.9 using `suso yum -y update` command:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libganglia.so.0.0.0 from install of ganglia-3.7.2-40.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libganglia-3.7.2-el7.x86_64
```

From Internet search, especially [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10891/what-is-a-transaction-check-error-yum-update), I'm guessing that the error seems to be yum trying to update ganglia from a newer version 3.7.2-40 to an old version 3.7.2. Instead of modifying `/etc/yum.conf` file to exclude updating ganglia, I would like to find out which repo lists package `libganglia-3.7.2` and then to exclude this older version in my `/etc/yum.repos.d/` dir. I don't know how to do that, can you please give me some instructions to accomplish these two tasks? Thanks.

Some information I think may be useful:

- Results of `yum whatprovides '*libganglia*'`:
  [image]
- Results of `yum list *libganglia*`:
  [image]